# Get the current month in full text in php

Tags: php, date

I want to echo the current month in full text. eg : june;

```
      echo date('M');
```

// result jun.

but i want to display full month. how can i do that.

Comment: I don't think you have search for it!

Answer (score 8):

You can use `date` with *F* (have a look at the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)).

So `date("F")` will output `June`.

Comment: That does not work for me